# Custom Exception not caught in Python Flask App

Tags: python, flask

I got a Flask app calling different modules. One of them eventually raises a NoPrice exception but the `except NoPrice` doesn't catch it as a NoPrice but `except Exception`catches it...

```
class NoPrice(Exception):
    pass
```

somewhere in a module

```
raise NoPrice('error')
```

in my flask app

```py
try:
    raise NoPrice('main')
except NoPrice as e:
    print('main')
except Exception as e:
    print('main2')

try:
    resp = alicia.create_predictions(select)
except NoPrice as e:
    print('main3')
except Exception as e:
    print('main4')
    print(repr(e))
    print(e)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

The output of this is

```
main
main4
NoPrice('No price found for material_reference 0148054b-e681-4fb6-9722-946f3cfa8529 the weight 1.7471266917293233', 'occurred at index 0')
('No price found for material_reference 0148054b-e681-4fb6-9722-946f3cfa8529 the weight 1.7471266917293233', 'occurred at index 0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c/main.py", line 71, in create_predictions_api
    resp = alicia.create_predictions(select)
  File "/absolutepath/app/alicia.py", line 703, in create_predictions
    self.set_machines_and_format()
  File "/absolutepath/app/alicia.py", line 574, in set_machines_and_format
    x["is_screenprinting_option"]), axis = 1)
  File "/absolutepath/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6913, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "/absolutepath/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 186, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/absolutepath/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 292, in apply_standard
    self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/absolutepath/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 321, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "/absolutepath/app/alicia.py", line 574, in <lambda>
    x["is_screenprinting_option"]), axis = 1)
  File "/absolutepath/app/alicia.py", line 359, in predict_price_relying_on_format
    output = Jerome(self.product, self.hipe_client_config).run(self.quote_input)
  File "/absolutepath/app/jerome/jerome.py", line 235, in run
    pliant = pliant_obj.price(quote_input, self.material_reference)
  File "/absolutepath/app/jerome/options_construction/pliant.py", line 66, in price
    quote_input['matter_margin_percentage'])
  File "/absolutepath/app/jerome/options_construction/pliant.py", line 52, in pliant
    raise NoPrice(f"No price found for material_reference {material_reference.id} the weight {x1}")
exceptions.NoPrice: ('No price found for material_reference 0148054b-e681-4fb6-9722-946f3cfa8529 the weight 1.7471266917293233', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Why doesn't the except NoPrice catch my exception ?

Shouldn't the ouput be

```
main
main3
```

My goal is ultimately to handle only my NoPrice exception

Comment: Have you tried to remove exception handlers or raise exception futher? What traceback is? Is it possible `my_function` can raise some other exception? I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: import traceback module, and then print it when your exception occurs: `print(traceback.format_exc())`. This will tell you exactly what exception is being raised.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce in a little script, I suspect something from the Flask Stack but I am not sure how this is possible

Comment: I have updated the output with more details about the caught exception and the traceback

Answer (score 0):

my_function must not be raising the NoPrice exception, and therefore it isn't caught in the 'main 3' section.

Comment: The object.my_function  was some template code from the little test I used to try to reproduced the issues. I've updated the sample of code with the original code.

Comment: The function create_prediction() doesnt directly call the raise NoPrice. You can find the original raise in the backtrace

Comment: In order to catch an exception, it must be raised. You say you expect 'main 3' to be printed, implying you expect "resp = alicia.create_predictions(select)" to raise a NoPrice exception. Does create_predictions have the ability to raise said exception?

Comment: Just to be sure, I've added `raise NoPrice('test')` as the first line of create_predictions. The ouput is the same. ```main
main4```